# cPanel's SMTP or google hosted SMTP?

Tags: php, email, spam

I'm wondering what mail servers I should use for sending mail through my website, avoiding them sent as spam.

1. Hostgator SMTP
2. google hosted SMTP

I found that to avoid a mail sent as spam it should have the same host in "From:" and "Received". How to overcome this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you should really check (or create) your dns [SPF record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework): it specifies which server is allowed to send email for your domain name. Hotmail and gmail users, among others, may find your emails in their junk folder if you set these incorrectly or not at all.

Also make sure you have a reverse dns record set to your domain name. your recipients Mail servers will check if your mail server's ip address is fixed or dynamic (if dynamic, it's most probably spam). See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup)

> checking the domain names in the rDNS
>   to see if they are likely from dialup
>   users, dynamically assigned addresses,
>   or other inexpensive internet
>   services. Owners of such IP addresses
>   typically assign them generic rDNS
>   names such as
>   "1-2-3-4-dynamic-ip.example.com."
>   Since the vast majority, but by no
>   means all, of e-mail that originates
>   from these computers is spam, many
>   spam filters refuse e-mail with such
>   rDNS names